# knockout.js and radio button within label needs to be clicked twice

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

I have this weird issue where I need to click the label twice for the radio button to select below.  Once its selected I can choose a different one and come back and the original then works on a single click.  It's just the initial click on each radio button that has me click it twice.  Any reason?

```
<label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="answer" data-bind="value: id, checked: $parent.answerId, disable: $parent.hasError()" /> <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this instead, `value: id()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptom: when clicking on a radio input the observable would get updated correctly, but the radio circle would only appear filled on the second click. I had only used the `checked:` binding, with no `value:` binding, and the `value=""` HTML attribute was set correctly.

The problem was that I had repeated the same markup twice in my page, and the HTML `name=""` attributes were not unique in the document. The solution was to remove the `name=""` HTML attributes altogether. They are not really needed if you are not submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a value and a checked attribute, but you only need one or the other.

```
<label class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="answer" data-bind="checked: $parent.answerId, disable: $parent.hasError()" /> <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
</label>
```

If you use checked it is hard to make it a group of radio buttons with only one selection so you may want to create a custom observable to handle reading and writing of the value like described here -

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: But doesnt the radio button need a value attribute for the checked to work?

Comment: The checked binding is a two-way data bound value attribute to use for check boxes that are registered to a boolean value

Comment: For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute. So, your parameter value should be a string. 

When the user changes which radio button is selected, KO will set your model property to equal the value attribute of the selected radio button.